# $addToSet is not updating the object in array?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm beginner in mongodb I want to add one object in **Array tag**. **ie:Array of Objects.**.I'm using **$addToSet Operator** but it's not working.
I have a collection like this:

```html
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c231693d1b726c55ec914a3"),
    "name" : "Christine Franklin",
    "degrees" : [ 
        {
            "level" : "Master",
            "major" : "Cs",
            "completion_year" : "2018",
            "faculty" : "AKz"
        }, 
        {
            "level" : "Bachelor",
            "major" : "Biology",
            "completion_year" : 2008,
            "faculty" : "Science"
        }
    ],
    "school_email" : "cfranklin@example.edu",
    "email" : "christine@example.com"
}
```

This is my schema:

```html
const schema=new mongoose.Schema({
    name:String,
    degrees:[String],
    school_email:String,
    email:String
});

const GradeDetails=mongoose.model('graduate',schema);
```

This is my code:

```html
 const result=await GradeDetails.update({"name" : "Christine Franklin"},{
        $addToSet:{
            "degrees":{
        "level" : "PG",
        "major" : "M.Tech",
        "completion_year" : "2018",
        "faculty" : "KG"
    }}
    });

    console.log(result);
```

Thanks in advance... can anyone solve this problem?

Comment: Is this Mongoose? If so, can you add the schema for `GradeDetails`?

Comment: I have added schema above..

Comment: Well your schema is telling Mongoose that `degrees` is an array of strings, not objects.

Comment: how to declare the type for Array of objects in mongoose schema above?

Comment: See https://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html

Answer (score 0):

Besides the problem with the badly matching types, did you check if you object was updated in the db and just not displayed correctly? If so, please add the flag `{ new : true }` to your update query options. Otherwise, the old object will be returned.